# Google Cloud LB: Change "server error" default html page

Tags: google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

By default, if the load balance can't find a backend to redirect traffic to, for example if all available backends are down, it shows this html page:

[image]

Transcript:

> #### Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

I would like to use my own static html page instead.
I saw this on the LB + Cloud storage page [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage):

> You can also configure a custom index page and a custom error page that will be served if the requested object doesn’t exist. This can be done by adding a Website Configuration to your Cloud Storage bucket. With a Website Configuration, you could serve a static webpage directly out of a Cloud Storage bucket from your own domain.

How would that work ?
I know how to host static page on cloud storage, but how would I use it with the LB ?

Comment: Feature request to vote on: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160192483

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, **you can't**, at least for now.

The [HTTP Load Balancer with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage) you found is in alpha, you will need to request a whitelist to try it. But it won't solve your problem.
Because as of now, there is no way to control a load balancer's redirection manully based on the backends' responses. I don't think that will ever be possible. It's not the purpose of a load balancer in GCP.

> You can also configure a custom index page and a custom error page that will be served if the requested object doesn’t exist.

The above statement only means that you can have a custom 404 page for unfound objects in the bucket. It's not meant to let you redirect traffic if your Back-services are down (502). There is a big difference between : I can't find a page, and Nothing is working because I don't have a server.

You can only redirect traffic coming from outside toward the inside of your network. You can't do the opposite. You can't ask the load balancer to redirect based on a response.

Instead of trying to make the 502 error page beautiful, ask yourself why you have it in the first place, and try to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I will take your word on it. Regarding your last comment - I disagree. There's no relation whatsoever between finding out why my website is down and making the error page less intimidating for our customers (beauty is not my aim here). I can actually do both! And regarding your opinion that this feature shouldn't exist, I also disagree. I'm not saying it's huge, just saying that I totally see why it's necessary.

Comment: I didn't mean that this feature shouldn't exist. It sure would be nice to have an option to redirect traffic if no backends are healthy. But I think it's logical that it doesn't. Kinda like it's normal to have an ugly 500 error if a single server is not responding, and we can't do much about it. But who knows, may be GCP will give us a nice solution soon :)